# How do I specify options in my f.collections_select menu that are not based off objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, ruby-on-rails-5, html-select

With Rails 5, how do I hard-code option and values for my `select` menu?  These options aren't based off objects.  Otherwise I could do

```
 <%= f.collection_select :my_field, @my_objects,:id,:name,{:prompt => "Select Object"} %>
```

Instead, I want the options to be rendered as

```
<option value="false">Above</option>
<option value="true">Below</option>
```

How do I construct my Rails object to render this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `select` with `options_for_select`

```
<%= f.select :my_field, options_for_select([["Above", "false"], ["Below", "true"]]),{:prompt => "Select Object"} %>
```

Which should produce the select with the below options

```
<option value="false">Above</option>
<option value="true">Below</option>
```